# ¿Cómo hacer push a 2 ramas distintas sin merge?

Tags: git, github, push, ramas-git

Ya tengo la rama master en el repositorio remoto, pero quiero tener otra version en una rama ya creada llamada withoutcomments y al dar push me dice esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé cómo solucionarlo, ojalá alguien me pueda apoyar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmm tal vez falta que le hagas **`git pull`** (así solo o con alguna de sus variantes)de la rama remota de withoutcomments a  tu withoutcomments local, y posteriormete **`git push -u origin withoutcomments`**

Ojo también en cómo llamas tus branches, en la pregunta tienes *withoutcomments y en la terminal `*withoutcommets` (sin la n)

Suerte!!

Comment: El problema es la segunda parte de tu respuesta.  Buen ojo! +1

Comment: Justo era eso jeje, muchas gracias!